# Ubuntu 15.04 reboots by itself

Tags: hp, 15.04

Ubuntu 15.04 reboots itself on my PC every few hours.
There is no error message on the screen.  I downgraded to 14.04 and still get the same problem.

Here is [product info](http://pastebin.com/bfscdQgQ)

There is no file in /var/crash.

here is `grep -i` [error syslog](http://pastebin.com/PC0SqJfn)

I installed Windows 10 and the computer stopped crashing.  I tried turning ACPI off, but then the keyboard worked erratically and video playback did not work.

I have had no problem on my other PC. Only the HP Envy DV7 crashes.

Comment: What could be more interesting is the portion of the log just before an unexpected reboot.

Comment: Here is the syslog http://southernpacificreview.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/05/syslog.txt

Comment: Here is product information:

Comment: I downgraded to 14.04 and have the same problem.  So I installed the Xen hypervisor and installed Ubuntu in that.  So far it is stable.

Comment: Were your able to more permanently fix the problem, perhaps by upgrading to 15.10?

Comment: Not at first.  But then Ubuntu pushed out an Ubuntu to 4.2.0-35-generic. and then the problem was fixed.   This case is the same as http://askubuntu.com/questions/753119/ubuntu-15-10-15-04-14-04-restarts-by-itself-debian-no-problem