# Network manager core dump 15.04

Tags: networking, network-manager

I am trying to get someone to respond to this question:

[Ubuntu 15.04 reboots by itself](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621291/ubuntu-15-04-reboots-by-itself)

But in the meantime I get this on Uuntu 15.04

nm-applet

(nm-applet:4109): nm-applet-WARNING **: Cannot grab information for modem at /org/freedesktop/ModemManager1/Modem/0: No ModemManager support
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Answer (score 0):

> It seems I was able to solve the problem. Not sure how that was
>   possible but there were two entries for my mobile broadband connection
>   listed. I never added a second one. However as described below I was
>   able to run the nm-applet using '--version'. This allowed me to remove
>   one of the entries for mobile broadband connections.

*source: [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/network-manager-applet/+bug/1458340)*